# Load-balancing UDP on localhost by source IP

Tags: nginx, udp, load-balancing

I have a server (openvpn) which is not multithreaded and hence does not take advantage of the multiple cores in the box. I'm trying to solve the problem by running multiple servers, each on a different port, e.g. 127.0.0.1:8000, 127.0.0.1:8001, ... then load balancing the exterior 1194 port based on the source IP -- openvpn uses UDP but all packets for a client must arrive at the same server.

Issue I'm running into is how to load balance. I tried IPVS, but it seems like it doesn't work with servers on the same host. Then tried nginx's new udp feature, but again no dice. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that plain old iptables can create such a load balancer, using  the HMARK target extension (see `man 8 iptables-extensions`).

Essentially the `HMARK` target can mark a packet based on a hash of specific IP tuple parameters, source IP and source port in my case, as these will be unique per client, even behind a NAT. Then I can route the packets to the appropriate localhost server based on the mark:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p udp --dport 1194 -j HMARK \
         --hmark-tuple src,sport --hmark-mod 2 \
         --hmark-rnd 0xcafeface --hmark-offset 0x8000

iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p udp -m mark --mark 0x8000 \
         -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8000

iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p udp -m mark --mark 0x8001 \
         -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8001
```

Remember to enable routing packets to localhost:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth0.route_localnet=1
```